# Asterisk/star in region description when doing multiple integrals

Tags: integration, multiple-integral

I have a double integral over some region A; region defined as:
$\{ (x,y) \in \Bbb{R} : x^2+y^2 \le 1, x \ast 4 + 3y^2 \le 2 \}$

Can someone please explain to me what exactly the $\ast$ means in this context?

Comment: Possibly a multiplication symbol, although I am not sure why the author did not just write "$4x$" in such a case. Anyways, without context on where you found the problem it is impossible to be sure.

Comment: It was a set of problems in my homework. It does use "$ax$" form elsewhere in the set when there is a multiplication

Comment: I read that it might mean that whatever is left of $\ast$ relates to the limits of the inner integral, while whatever is right of it relates to the outer integral. Is this common?

Comment: I have never seen that notation and I have never seen someone not write out the integral with the limits if order mattered. I personally, if you do not have the chance to ask a whoever wrote the question, would take it as a multiplication symbol because otherwise you have that $4+3y^{2}\leq2$ which implies that $y^{2}\leq\frac{-2}{3}$ which never happens for $y\in \mathbb{R}$, and since a lone standing $x$ means nothing, your set would be $\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^{2}:x^2+y^2\leq 1\}$ the unit disc in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$, which one can usually express more simply then what you have been given.